# How to make an overloaded function a dependent name, so two-phase lookup finds it?

Tags: c++

Look at this example:

```
template <typename TYPE>
struct Foo {
    static constexpr auto a = bar(TYPE());
    static constexpr auto b = static_cast<int (*)(TYPE)>(bar);
};

struct Bar {};

constexpr int bar(Bar) {
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    auto a = Foo<Bar>::a;
    auto b = Foo<Bar>::b;
}
```

At the definition of `Foo`, `bar` is unknown to the compiler. But it's a not a problem at the initialization of `Foo::a`, because `bar(TYPE())` is a dependent expression, so ADL lookup will find `bar` later at the second phase of lookup. But it's a problem at the initialization of `Foo::b`, because `bar` is not a dependent expression, so the compiler complains that `bar` is undeclared ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/88T13qr76)). So I can call `bar` (`Foo::a`), but I cannot take its address (`Foo::b`).

Is there any trick so can I get the address of `bar` (besides the obvious solution that I move `Foo` after `bar`)? For example, somehow make an expression which is dependent on `TYPE` and returns `bar`'s address?

Comment: You can use forward declarations to help untangle them, but that's pretty close to the obvious solution you've already mentioned.

Comment: @Eljay: thanks for the suggestion, but it has almost the same problem as reordering (it would make things extremely inconvenient), so it is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can’t**, unfortunately: even if `bar` were somehow dependent, ADL would never be performed for it since it isn’t a function being **called**.  (Put differently, unqualified names that aren’t the function name in a dependent call are always looked up in the template definition.)  The closest you can do is to use (and specialize!) a **trait** and write `bar_trait<TYPE>::bar` or make your own **wrapper** function for `bar` and take the address of that (which might or might not be good enough).